# An example of 4D Hypersurface in 3D

Tags: manifolds, 3d, curvature

Number of combinations of 4 dimensions choosing 3 at a time is 4.

Someone please give a description of a most elementary 4 Dimensional Hyper

surface which has its four 3D intersections with coordinate planes as:

*( a plane, a cone, a cylinder, and a  sphere )* from which hopefully one gains

an understanding/feel/reality of the 4D.

EDIT1:

The way I imagine a particular case: Three mutually perpendicular planes can cut a cone along an ellipse,hyperbola and pair of straight lines. The 3 planar space curves can be re-joined together with a zero Gauss curvature surface, re-constructing the cone.

Three small circles on a sphere  are made by coordinate planes cutting a sphere  whose center is not the origin.They can be re-joined together to get back the sphere, or even we can employ a minimal surface run through these 3 circles  using a soap film or even a surface of constant mean curvature.

Possessing certain analogous higher curvature properties ( do not know what they are), by the same token arbitrary surfaces should be capable of being integrated to form hyper-surfaces, or so it appears to me.

Comment: Why do you think there is such a hypersurface? Also, notice that such a hypersurface generally intersects with many different planes---by "its four $3$D intersections cut out" do you mean the intersection with the four coordinates planes?

Comment: Yes cut by coordinate planes. Why cannot a hyper-surface be assembled/integrated/synthesized from 2D surfaces? I mention this also in EDIT1 of the question.